# How to get content uri from android uri for pdf files - React native

Tags: android, react-native, uri, android-contentprovider

I am working on an offline app where I want to open and make changes to an offline document.
I am able to open the file from the android uri path i.e. `/data/user/0/com.nativetemplate/files/files/default/documents/3377699720528075@1634821435640`
but my requirement is to get the content:// uri path so I can save the changes made on the file.
eg: `content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3D3ANW16SOSAt4EvkKHsYo_159-fKCSyFbzE4zHcCNeew3N7oDXd0jgvbNFDM%3D`

how do I get the content uri?

My requirement can also work if the file is converted into base64. But as I have android uri path I think I would need an API to read the file from the uri.

please provide me with any suggestions you may have.

Thanks

Comment: If your app can read the file using a file path than your app can also write the changes to the same path. I dont underdtand why you need a content scheme uri. And why are pdf files not mentioned in your post?

Comment: Hi @blackapps, I am using pdftron which is able to open the pdf files with the android path uri. However to save the document they expect a content uri.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. What is pdftron? A different app? Or a library used in your app? You should tell more.

Comment: PDFTron is an SDK to render files such as pdfs and too add functionalities such as annotations. They provide apis to use out of the box to add/ save changes on rendered pdfs. The save document API https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-react-native/blob/master/API.md#savedocument expects me to use file uri as content uri or a base64 string file as input but I have the android path uri as mentioned above.

Comment: even to convert the file from android path uri to base64 string I would need the file reader api I assume @blackapps

Comment: I still do not know what pdftron has to do with your app. Is it part of your app or a different app that you try to let handle a pdf file?

Comment: `this._viewer.saveDocument().then((filePath) => {
  console.log('saveDocument:', filePath);
});
` Just a file path. Nothing about a content scheme.